# Numbers whose powers approach integers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let d(x) denote the distance from x to the nearest integer.

Are there any non-integral numbers X for which the sequence d(X), d(X^2), d(X^3), etc. converges to 0?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to exclude the trivial case where X is between -1 and 1. I was looking for more interesting cases.

Comment: Not a research level question, voting to close.

Comment: Look up Pisot numbers on Google.

Comment: $X=1/2$ seems to work.

Comment: It's disappointing to see the trivial answers of magnitude less than $1$ repeated. $\phi = (\sqrt 5 + 1)/2$ has this property. It follows from the closed form expression for Lucas numbers $L(n) = 
\phi^n + (-\phi)^{-n}$, and a similar argument works for other Pisot numbers. Nevertheless, this is not research level. 

Comment: Hi yrudoy: I can't comment on the level or interest of the question, it being far from my area of expertise. But the style can be improved. A good mathoverflow question includes some background and motivation: Why is this a question you are interested in? Why should I be interested in it? How does it relate to your research? Please read carefully http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask and look over other successful MO questions. If you still think a version of this question is appropriate, edit it, and either flag for moderator attention or leave a comment at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/ .

Answer (score 5):

Even assuming that $|x| > 1$, there
are some counter-examples, for example, as noted in the comments (exercise!)
$$x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
Let $\|\alpha\|$ denote the distance from a real
number $\alpha$ to the closest integer.
It is an interesting problem to classify the set $S$ of
real numbers $|x| > 1$ such that
$$\lim_{\rightarrow} \|x^n\| = 0.$$
A special subset of $S$ is given by the set of  Pisot-Vijayaraghavan (or PV)  numbers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%2DVijayaraghavan_number

which are real algebraic integers $\theta$ all
of whose conjugates have absolute  value
less than $1$. (The example above is of this class.)
In this case, the convergence of $\|x^n\|$ to zero is exponential.
Conversely,
 if $x \in S$ and the convergence is
fast enough ($L^2$), then $x$ is a PV number (this was proved by Pisot).
However, it is not known whether there are
any other real numbers  in $S$.
Even worse, it's very hard to tell whether any
given number (say $e$ or $\pi$) lies in $S$.
On the other hand, a theorem of Koksma says that for almost
all $x > 1$, the fractional parts of $x^n$ are
uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$.